# Finding the smallest power of $A$ such that $A^n = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\-1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ then the smallest positive positive integer $n$ such that $A^n = I$ is :

(a) $1$ (b) $2$ (c) $4$ (d) $6$

proof: option (d) 6.

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\lambda^2 - \lambda + 1$. So the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\omega, \omega^2$ where $\omega$ is a cube root of $-1$ and not equal to $-1$. So the eigenvalues of $A^n$ are $\omega^n$ and $\omega^{2n}$ and the eigenvalue of $I$ is $1$, so $\omega^{2n} = 1$ and $\omega^n = 1$ which implies $n$ as a multiple of $3$ and $2$ which means $6$ is the only option we have.

Is my reasoning correct?? And can we solve this without using eigenvalues?

Comment: Of course you can solve this without eigenvalues. Just calculate the powers of $A$.

Comment: That'll be cumbersome

Comment: I’d also do it this way. Id say that since the characteristic polynomial divides $x^3+1$, which in turn divides $x^6-1$, all eigenvalues are sixth roots of 1, so $A^6=I$.

Comment: Oh, just noticed, $\omega^2$ is not the other eigevalue of $A$, but rather $\overline\omega = \omega^5$ is.

Comment: I made a mistake there

Comment: Exercise.- A rotation of $60^{\circ}$ has a matrix whose $6$-power is obviously the identity and such a matrix can be represented as $$\begin{vmatrix}1/2&-\sqrt3/2\\\sqrt3/2&1/2\end{vmatrix}$$ Find a relation between this matrix and $A$..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since $\lambda^2-\lambda +1$ is characteristic, it follows that $A^2 - A + I = 0$, i.e. \begin{align}
A^2 &= A - I\\
A^3 &= A^2 - A = -I\\
A^4 &= -A \\
A^5 &= A^2\cdot A^3 = I - A\\
A^6 &= A^3\cdot A^3 = I.
\end{align}

Comment: Interesting approach

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the eigenvalues of $A$ are the cube roots of $\color{red}-1$, distinct from $-1$ itself (since $\lambda^3+1=(\lambda+1)(\lambda^2-\lambda+1)$). So, $A^3=-\operatorname{Id}_3$, and therefore the answer is $6$.

Comment: oh yeah, It should be cube roots of -1, I get it. Anyway, can we solve this without using eigenvalues?

Comment: Sure. Cumpute $A^2$ and $A^3$. You will see that $A^3=\operatorname{Id}_3$. It follows that the answer is $6$.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalues are imaginary and $\det(A)=1$.

Therefore the matrix has a [real Jordan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices) that is a rotation matrix with $\cos\phi=\frac 12 \operatorname{tr}(A) = \frac 12$.

So $\phi = \frac\pi 3\implies A^6=I$.

Answer (score 0):

Squaring $A$ twice shows that
$$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1\\-1 & 0\end{bmatrix},\qquad
A^4=(A^2)^2=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix},$$
so by elimination the correct answer must be d.